# Multiple applications of >> in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

Suppose I have Airflow tasks like this:

```py
apple_task = DummyOperator(
  task_id='apple'
)

banana_task = DummyOperator(
  task_id='banana'
)

cherry_task = DummyOperator(
  task_id='cherry'
)

apple_task >> cherry_task
banana_task >> cherry_task
```

Do the repeated applications of `>>` stack or replace the previous one?

What will the graph look like?

---

Airflow `2.2.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They stack, as in `apple_task` and `banana_task` will be ran in parallel, both must succeed to run `cherry_task`.

It's equivalent to `[apple_task, banana_task] >> cherry_task`.

The scheduler parses the DAGs (every 30s by default), and the DAG is read and the graph is constructed. An advantage to specifying task dependencies as you did, you can dynamically create tasks at parse time - as they're just python objects.

The DAG documentation page has some more examples under the task dependencies heading [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html?highlight=chain#task-dependencies) and the control flow heading [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html?highlight=chain#control-flow).

Comment: "will be ran in parallel" I guess strictly speaking they "*may* be run in parallel"